# MongoDB . Dealing with arrays and calculations

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Am struggling in finding a way to get the number of product orders in specific period  . I want to get the sum of product orders since 2 days ago specifically (I want the sum of orders between 21-March & 19-March) 
So we will not add the orders from 17-March to the result ..

here is a sample record

```
{
"productId": "32947681206",
"category": "Furniture",
"orders": [{
        "date": ISODate("2019-03-17T00:00:00.000+0000"),
        "orders": NumberInt(3)
    },
    {
        "date": ISODate("2019-03-19T00:00:00.000+0000"),
        "orders": NumberInt(3)
    },
    {
        "date": ISODate("2019-03-20T00:00:00.000+0000"),
        "orders": NumberInt(2)
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Greetings friend, If you want the best answers to your questions, please frame them according to these guides: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve > For a question like yours, we all want to know what you tried and what didn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to conditionally ([$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html)) sum array elements:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            sum: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$orders",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                        $add: [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                                $cond: [
                                    { $gte: [ "$$this.date", ISODate("2019-03-19T00:00:00.000+0000") ] },
                                    "$$this.orders",
                                    0
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```